# How to change the default save location for Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, configuration, customization, bookmarks

When I make a new bookmark in Firefox it is automatically saved to the "Unsorted Bookmarks" section, but I  would prefer it go to just straight to the "Bookmarks Toolbar", so how can I change the default save location for new bookmarks in Firefox 46.0.1 running on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in method for doing that.
But you can just **drag and drop the page title from the tab to the Bookmarks Toolbar**.

[image]

[source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986106#answer-533052)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no option for this in `about:config` but you can add bookmark by clicking on the star and than clicking it again allow you to change added bookmark location, or you can immediately  double click star and pick location or use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut.

You can also check this [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/)